# Crop and Resize Image - Replace GD with imagick

Tags: php, gd, crop, image-resizing, imagick

I want to replace all the GD code with imagick code from the 
"cropping jquery plugin" from [www.croppic.net](http://www.croppic.net)

**Here is the original file**
https://github.com/sconsult/croppic/blob/master/img_crop_to_file.php

**what I have done**

```
    // original sizes
    $imgInitW               = $_POST['imgInitW'];
    $imgInitH               = $_POST['imgInitH'];

    // resized sizes
    $imgW                   = $_POST['imgW'];
    $imgH                   = $_POST['imgH'];

    // offsets
    $imgY1                  = $_POST['imgY1'];
    $imgX1                  = $_POST['imgX1'];

    // crop box
    $cropW                  = $_POST['cropW'];
    $cropH                  = $_POST['cropH'];

    // rotation angle
    $angle                  = $_POST['rotation'];

    //quali
    $jpeg_quality           = 100;

/*  resize the original image to size of editor */
//  $imgUrl = '/kunden/40/0_org.jpg';
//  $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgUrl);
//  $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgUrl);
//  $type = '.jpeg';
//  $resizedImage = imagecreatetruecolor($imgW, $imgH);
//  imagecopyresampled($resizedImage, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imgW, $imgH, $imgInitW, $imgInitH);    
    $im = new imagick('/kunden/40/0_org.jpg');
    $im->resizeImage($imgW, $imgH, 0, 0, false);        

/*  rotate the rezized image */
//  $rotated_image = imagerotate($resizedImage, -$angle, 0);
    $im->rotateimage('#fff', -$angle);

/*  find new width & height of rotated image */
//  $rotated_width = imagesx($rotated_image);
//  $rotated_height = imagesy($rotated_image);
    $d = $im->getImageGeometry();
    $rotated_width = $d['width'];
    $rotated_height = $d['height'];

/*  diff between rotated & original sizes */
    $dx = $rotated_width - $imgW;
    $dy = $rotated_height - $imgH;

/*  crop rotated image to fit into original rezized rectangle */
//  $cropped_rotated_image = imagecreatetruecolor($imgW, $imgH);
//  imagecolortransparent($cropped_rotated_image, imagecolorallocate($cropped_rotated_image, 0, 0, 0));
//  imagecopyresampled($cropped_rotated_image, $rotated_image, 0, 0, $dx / 2, $dy / 2, $imgW, $imgH, $imgW, $imgH);
    $im->cropImage($imgW,$imgH, $dx/2, $dy/2); // i think this is not correct

/*  crop image into selected area */
//  $final_image = imagecreatetruecolor($cropW, $cropH);
//  imagecolortransparent($final_image, imagecolorallocate($final_image, 0, 0, 0));
//  imagecopyresampled($final_image, $cropped_rotated_image, 0, 0, $imgX1, $imgY1, $cropW, $cropH, $cropW, $cropH);

/*  save image */
//  imagejpeg($final_image, $output_filename.'.jpg', $jpeg_quality);
    $im->writeImage('/kunden/40/0.jpg');
```

The result is an black image with an incorrect width and height.
Hope somebody can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't a code writing service - why not narrow it down to a single thing that is going wrong, rather than asking people to just debug your code
http://sscce.org/

Comment: I have to agree with Danack -- there's too much going on here. Can you please narrow the question down to the piece of code that's having problems?

Comment: So, you'll spend some reputation on trying to get someone to answer the question, but not any effort to reduce the question to a bit of code that fits on a screen. Also, you ought to post an example input and output image.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in line with resizeImage method.
Please pay attention to 3rd and 4th params: int $filter , float $blur. You can find more details [here](http://php.net/manual/de/imagick.resizeimage.php)

Try to replace this line with the following to get a proper result:

```
$im->resizeImage($imgW, $imgH, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1, false);
```

You can play with a demo with different filters [here](http://phpimagick.com/Imagick/resizeImage)

Answer (score 1):

**This is the new image width and height.**

```
$new_width = $max_width = $img_width = $image->getImageWidth();
$new_height = $max_height = $img_height = $image->getImageHeight();
```

**follow these steps**

```
 if (($img_width / $img_height) >= ($max_width / $max_height)) {
                $new_width = 0; // Enables proportional scaling based on max_height
                $x = ($img_width / ($img_height / $max_height) - $max_width) / 2;
            } else {
                $new_height = 0; // Enables proportional scaling based on max_width
                $y = ($img_height / ($img_width / $max_width) - $max_height) / 2;
            }
```

**and at final step**

```
$success = $image->resizeImage(
            $new_width,
            $new_height,
            isset($options['filter']) ? $options['filter'] : imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,
            isset($options['blur']) ? $options['blur'] : 1,
            $new_width && $new_height // fit image into constraints if not to be cropped
        );
        if ($success && $crop) {
            $success = $image->cropImage(
                $max_width,
                $max_height,
                $x,
                $y
            );
            if ($success) {
                $success = $image->setImagePage($max_width, $max_height, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        $type = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, '.'), 1));
        switch ($type) {
            case 'jpg':
            case 'jpeg':
                if (!empty($options['jpeg_quality'])) {
                    $image->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
                    $image->setImageCompressionQuality($options['jpeg_quality']);
                }
                break;
        }
        if (!empty($options['strip'])) {
            $image->stripImage();
        }
        return $success && $image->writeImage($new_file_path);
```

this is the code worked on me :) try and play

Comment: actually i have done this a long time ago and it takes me a crucial time to solve it.i have the same issue and and i corrected it with this code :)